# Show MS Excel sheet in SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, list, excel, reporting-services, reports

I have an Excel document where we track team projects' travel periods.
Preview
[image]

*Info:*
Users are ordered in 1st column. Bellow is Projects coloring legend.
Team members are on site like User1, 20.11.2016. - 11.12.2016.

My question is, Is something similar possible to achieve in SharePoint?
List with Gantt view came up my mind, but I don't know how to achieve to have every travel of user in same item. I would have to add new columns every time user goes to site the other way I know is to edit item and remove current dates and put new data, which I don't want to do.
Also Excel sheet preview in web part is not an option.

Comment: Are you looking for the ability to edit directly in SharePoint?

Comment: it would be great. but if it is not possible, I would consider other options.

Comment: Are you currently using MS Web Apps?

Comment: Not sure if I understand question. We use MS web apps on our web application.

Comment: This is what I am referring to:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx

Comment: Thank you on suggestion, but this is not what I asked for. We already have that activated on our farm.

Answer (score -1):

This is totally achievable in SharePoint, but not out of the Box. You can do this with a web app. If you don't have the resources to do it yourself, consider outsourcing. I'm not to sure why Flat Banana's suggestion is not what you are looking for, it seemed good to me. Perhaps you need to review your needs and see what's available in the SharePoint MarketPlace.

Comment: I already wrote in my question that MS Excel sheet preview in web part I don't want. I want something like Gantt view of custom list or task list with timeline.

Comment: Well have you looked in the O365 Sharepoint Marketplace at https://store.office.com/en-001/appshome.aspx?productgroup=SharePoint ?